# Take an array of words, return the array of words not exceeding max_length characters (reject)

Tags: arrays, ruby

I working on an exercise where I need to use .reject to sort some items in an array.
Here is the code I'm trying:

```
def short_words(array, max_length)
  array.reject { |words, value| words if value > max_length }
end
```

> TODO: Take an array of words, return the array of words not exceeding max_length characters. You should use Enumerable#reject.

Comment: Start here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject

Answer (score 0):

The array is a list of words. The `reject` methods takes these words one by one and decides which ones to ehm... reject. So in the block it is much clearer to refer to them as `|word|`. To determine the amount of characters strings happen to have a `size` method (`word.size`). `value` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.size` on each string in the array and compare it against you `max_length`

```
array = %w(spain france ireland uk bosnia portugal)
array.reject { |term| term.size > 5 }
=> ["spain", "uk"]
```